# iPhone Development: MapKit with CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, mapkit

Is there a good resource (book, article/tutorial, video, audio) on working with both MapKit and CoreData together? An article with some tips and tricks to efficiently utilize the memory and avoid running in to memory warning situations? I appreciate any personal advises that you can give me, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be such resources, but they aren't really necessary.

Core Data and MapKit are very separate frameworks and you should be able to use them both in an app successfully by applying the appropriate tips and tricks for each separately.

Core Data has been covered by many of the Cocoa blogs. For example, check out this [search](http://www.cimgf.com/index.php?s=core+data&sbutt=Go) on COCOA IS MY GIRLFRIEND. Marcus Zarra wrote the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356328) on Core Data.

For MapKit, I recommend anything that Bill Dudney has done. He has been on some podcast(s) and has a [screencast](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdmapkit/using-map-kit) at the Pragmatic Bookshelf and a chapter in [this book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development).